# Determine the matrix in the canonical basis of $ \mathbb {R}^ 3 $ of the orthogonal projector on $\text {im} (h).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

The space $ \mathbb {R}^3 $ is endowed with its usual scalar product, noted $ \langle. ,. \rangle $ for which the canonical basis $ \mathcal {B} = (e_1, e_2, e_3) $ is orthonormal.

We denote by $ h $ the endomorphism of $ \mathbb {R}^3 $ whose canonical matrix is

$$H=\left(\begin{matrix}1& -2& 3\\-2 &3 &-4\\3& -4 &5\end{matrix}\right)$$

**Problem**

Determine the matrix in the canonical basis of $ \mathbb {R}^ 3 $ of the orthogonal projector on $\text {im} (h)$.

An idea please.

Comment: Here's an idea: Assuming im(h) is a plane, find its normal vector by finding two vectors which span im(h) and taking their cross product.

Comment: Another idea: Find a linear dependence relation between the columns of the matrix, which will give you an element of the kernel. Since $A$ is symmetric, $(x, Ay) = (Ax, y)$ so the kernel is perpendicular to the image.